# Integration substitution, Curve Length

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Length of curve $(t, \log t)$ from $1$ to $2$.

$\int_1^2 \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}\ \operatorname d t$

Substituting in $u^2=1+t^2$,  I got the following.

$\int_\sqrt2^\sqrt5 \frac{u^2}{u^2-1}du$

I should note, the mentioned substitution was listed as a hint to be able to evaluate the integral. However, nothing comes to mind as to simplify it after using the hint.

Using Wolfram to evaluate the integral it looks exceedingly complex given the nature of the book I got it out of, so I think I may have done something wrong.

This problem is from Lang's Calculus of Several Variables; chapter 2, subsection 2, exercise 5.

Thoughts on how this substitution actually makes this integral simpler?

Edit:
The answer I got, by the partial fraction decomposition is $\sqrt5 - \sqrt2 +\frac{1}{2}\left[ \log \frac {\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt2-1} - \log \frac {\sqrt5+1}{\sqrt2+1}\right]$.

I see  Lang simplified in some other way, but a calculator reveals they're identical.

Comment: Don't you think that there is a problem around $0$ ?

Comment: The length of that curve isn't finite, since $\ln(t)$ has a vertical asymptote $t=0$. So the integral is divergent, and would be even if your integration limits after the substitutions were correct. Check if you managed to copy it from the book without accident, please.

Comment: I went and double checked, and I did actually write down the wrong limits of integration. That aside, I have corrected it, and am asking about how the substitution actually simplifies it.

Comment: If $u^2 = 1+t^2$, then you still have the problem of the disappearing square root here. 
Also... who is $x$ in your integration? How do the bounds of integration change with your substitution?

Comment: sorry, habitual. too used to writing x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}=1+\frac1{u^2-1}.$$

The two terms have an elementary antiderivative. If you don't know the second, decompose in simple fractions.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $(t,\log t)$ shows clearly that the arc length between $t\in (0,1)$ is infinite. That is, the integral cannot be convergent.

[image]

Comment: You're right, I have corrected the post

Comment: This shouldn't get down-voted. The OP made an edit. Originally this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: You can rewrite this as,

$$ \int_{1}^2 \frac{1}{t}  \cdot \sqrt{1+t^2} \ dt$$

Then if you let $u = 1+t^2$ , we have $du = 2t \ dt $. Can you go from here?